# Bootstrap textbox (input) full width is not working inside of a form

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.4.1 and i am trying to extend a textbox (input) filed to full width inside of a form and i am using bootstrap grid system columns to do this but it seems it not working.. the issue is when i give **col-md-12** then column it self take full width but text box is not..when i put **style="max-width=100%"** inside of textbox then it take full width but its not responsive.. any help is much appreciated. i have attached some pics.

my code:

```
<div class="row" style="border: 5px solid red;">
<div class="col-sm-12" style="border: 5px solid green;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="AssetTagId" class="control-label">Asset Tag Id1</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="AssetTagId" id="AssetTagId" ng-model="asset.AssetTagId" ng-maxlength="32" required style="border: 5px solid pink;"/> <!--style="max-width: 100%"-->
            <span class="text-danger" ng-show="(frmAddAsset.AssetTagId.$touched || frmAddAsset.AssetTagId.$dirty) && frmAddAsset.AssetTagId.$invalid">
                <span ng-show="frmAddAsset.AssetTagId.$error.required">AssetTagId is required</span>
                <span ng-show="frmAddAsset.AssetTagId.$error.maxlength">AssetTagId must be less than or equal to 32</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mcGc.png)

Comment: Will you include your full html? I don't understand what you mean by not responsive-- it's col-md-12/col-sm-12, it's going to take 12 columns which is the full width.

Comment: yes it is..as attached picture border take full width but textbox is not (Note: I am using this in a MVC project in Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PageTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PageTitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PageTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="form-group">
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>
</div>
```